# kdesudo - can it return before spawned process closes?

Tags: command-line, sudo

`kdesudo` doesn't return until the process started with it exits.  So, if I want to start three processes all at the same time, I have to use three terminal tabs.  I'd rather use one tab that returns to the bash prompt as soon as the process, say `konsole` is launched.

That would enable me to launch any number of processes from that one terminal tab.  I could then automate it with a script, and launch the processes one by one from there.  Is there a way to make `kdesudo` or `kdesu` or any similar programs work that way?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be

```
sudo bash -c "command 1 & command2 & command3 &"
```

The `&` symbol sends a process to the background. The `-c` flag to `bash` tells it to launch a new instance and execute the commands given by `-c`. So, the command above will launch all three programs at once.

However, if you want to do this in a script, don't use `sudo` in it at all. Just launch the *script* with `sudo`. For example:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash 

konsole &
firefox &
xclock &
$ sudo ./foo.sh
```